# Inspect how requests routed through a proxy look to their destination

Tags: http, proxy, request

My web app makes request to third party servers, and we sometimes route them trough proxies.  I'd like to be able to "see what they see" -- see what the request looks like once its been routed through the proxy.

Specifically, I'm interested in how much identifying information about the source (my web app) is left in the request once it reaches the destination, having been routed through the proxy.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?  Maybe a web service that will just echo back all the information about the incoming request in the outgoing response?

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer, but maybe you can try:

http://www.cantoni.org/2012/01/08/simple-webservice-echo-test

And the other 2 webs mentioned there:
http://respondto.it/
http://requestb.in/

To setup a URL to send your requests and see if the info provided helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just stating this as an idea that came to me.  You could try sending requests to **your own** URL, which you control (i.e. a resource in your own web application).  That way, you can use your debugging infrastructure or other facilities (basically anything you want) to inspect the request that's coming into your application.  It seems to me this might be the most powerful / easiest way to do this.  It won't let you test the URL you were trying to test, but in terms of proxy visibility, it might be what you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the proxy supports the TRACE method and the Max-Forwards header you can use that. Not all do, however.